# Find list of student that takes exactly the same course SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen many of such problems, but still do not understand how to do after reviewing the other questions here.

```
Select s1.email
From student s, student s1
where s1.sname <> 'Alice'
and not exists (select 1
                from enrol e, course c, enrol e1
                where s.sname = 'Alice'
                and s.sid = e.sid
                and s1.sid = e1.sid         
                and e1.code <> e.code );
```

Please refer to: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaaf58/5

This is my sample database, added in some dummy values so that i can test out this SQL query.

- What i am trying to do is to find the list of students that have taken the exact same courses as this particular student called alice.
- Many of the SQL queries that i have seen uses not exists. So i tried to implement it but failed. I should get b@hotmail instead of b@hotmail and c@hotmail. (Since only bob took exactly same course as alice)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Alice enrolls for multiple courses you want the other students to enroll for those exact courses right?

Comment: Yes i do. Only display those that enroll the exact same courses as Alice.

Comment: Are you trying to get familiarized with `not exists()` or do you just want the result? If what you want is just the result, then try this query `select distinct s.email from student s, enrol e, course c where s.sname <> 'Alice' and e.sid = s.sid and e.code in (select c1.code from student s1, enrol e1, course c1 where s1.sname = 'Alice' and e1.sid = s1.sid and e1.code = c1.code);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT s.sid,s.email,GROUP_CONCAT(e.code ORDER BY code) course_list
    FROM student s
    JOIN enrol e ON e.sid=s.sid
    WHERE s.sname<>'Alice'
    GROUP BY s.sid,s.email
  ) q
WHERE course_list=(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(e.code ORDER BY code) course_list
        FROM enrol e
        JOIN student s ON e.sid=s.sid
        WHERE s.sname='Alice'
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select email 
from student where sid in 
(select distinct sid from enrol where code in 
 (select distinct code from enrol where sid in 
  (select sid from student where sname = 'Alice') --In case you have more than one Alice students it still get all classmate of all Alice
 )
)
and sname <> 'Alice'
```